# Python Pandas table manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
    broker1  broker2  broker3  ticker
0   val1     val2     val3     tick1
1   val4     None     val6     tick2
```

I will like to manipulate it (not sure what is the term for this: pivot? reverse groupby?) in a way such that they are sorted by its individual values, ie:

```
    ticker  ticker_b  broker
0   tick1    val1     broker1
1   tick1    val2     broker2
2   tick1    val3     broker3
3   tick2    val4     broker1
4   tick2    val6     broker2
```

Is there a way to do this using pandas? Will really appreciate any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), which "unpivots" a table:

```
In [46]: df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO("""    broker1  broker2  broker3  ticker
    ...: 0   val1     val2     val3     tick1
    ...: 1   val4     None     val6     tick2"""), sep='\s+')

In [47]: df = df.replace('None', float('nan'))

In [48]: melted = df.melt(id_vars=("ticker",),
    ...:                  var_name="broker",
    ...:                  value_name="ticker_b").\
    ...:     dropna().\
    ...:     sort_values(["ticker", "ticker_b"])

In [49]: melted
Out[49]: 
  ticker   broker ticker_b
0  tick1  broker1     val1
2  tick1  broker2     val2
4  tick1  broker3     val3
1  tick2  broker1     val4
5  tick2  broker3     val6
```

Answer (score 0):

Also managed to do it using `concat`, although Ilja Everila's answer was better:

```
oldcols = ["broker1","broker2","broker3"]
newcols = ["ticker","ticker_b","broker"]
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=newcols)
for col in oldcols:
    tmpdf = df.loc[:,["ticker",col]]
    tmpdf.columns = newcols[0:2]
    tmpdf[newcols[-1]] = col
    newdf = pd.concat([newdf,tmpdf])
newdf.dropna(subset=["ticker"], inplace=True)
```